# MediaConvert thumbnails colors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert, aws-elemental

I have a strange issue with MediaConvert, where thumbnails that MediaConvert generates appear to be of different color than the actual video that MediaConvert creates.

On the left it's a frame of the video, on the right is the thumbnail generated. The behaviour is consistent for all videos, this is just an example

[image]

I'm not doing any color corrections to the thumbnails, my config is simply

```
                    Name: "File Group",
                    OutputGroupSettings: {
                        Type: "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
                        FileGroupSettings: {
                            Destination: `${data.inputDirectory}/thumbnails/${data.name}`,
                        },
                    },
                    Outputs: [
                        {
                            ContainerSettings: {
                                Container: "RAW",
                            },
                            VideoDescription: {
                                CodecSettings: {
                                    Codec: "FRAME_CAPTURE",
                                    FrameCaptureSettings: {
                                        MaxCaptures: 1,
                                        Quality: 80,
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                            Extension: "jpg",
                            NameModifier: "-thumb",
                        },
                    ],
                },
```

Is this normal? Shouldn't the thumbs match the video at all times? Am I supposed to now do manual color correction with the settings?
We recently switched from AWS Elastic Transcoder and did not have the same issues there with videos that were generated in the same way

Our videos are prepared with ffmpeg & hevc_videotoolbox before being sent to MediaConvert

Answer (score 0):

Looks like different color space settings are getting used by default on the thumbnail.

Try explicitly setting the thumbnail color space conversion to "ColorSpaceConversion": "FORCE_601"  ( "Force Rec. 601" in the Console).